# Convert a list of arrays into ip ranges

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know of a way in Ruby, or even through a web service, if there's a tool that will take a bunch of ip addresses (currently about 2 million of them) in a file and convert them to ip ranges like 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the IP address to 32 bit integer (Assume you're dealing with IPv4 address according to your post), remove the duplicates, sort them, and do the merge. After that, convert the integers back to IP string:

```
require 'ipaddr'

def to_ranges(ips)
  ips = ips.map{|ip| IPAddr.new(ip).to_i }.uniq.sort

  prev = ips[0]
  ips
    .slice_before {|e|
      prev2, prev = prev, e
      prev2 + 1 != e
    }
    .map {|addrs| if addrs.length > 1 then [addrs[0], addrs[-1]] else addrs end }
    .map {|addrs| addrs.map{|ip| IPAddr.new(ip, Socket::AF_INET)}.join("-") }
end

# some ip samples
ips = (0..255).map{|i| ["192.168.0.#{i}", "192.168.1.#{i}", "192.168.2.#{i}"] }.reduce(:+)
ips += ["192.168.3.0", "192.168.3.1"]
ips += ["192.168.3.5", "192.168.3.6"]
ips += ["192.168.5.1"]
ips += ["192.168.6.255", "192.168.7.0", "192.168.7.1"]

p to_ranges(ips)
# => ["192.168.0.0-192.168.3.1", "192.168.3.5-192.168.3.6", "192.168.5.1", "192.168.6.255-192.168.7.1"]
```

Reading IP addresses from file and storing them in an array should be relatively easy. 2 million IP addresses is a small set. You don't need to worry to much about the memory usage. (If it really matters, you may need to implement a algorithm to incrementally convert and merge the addresses)

BTW, I found the handy method [**Enumerable#slice_before**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) when solving your problem.